# Knockout binding not working - ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, data-binding, knockout.js

I have an update page form where I am trying to load existing user data when page loads. User can then modify the values and hit submit which will cause the data to be saved. I am unable to bind the data properly using Knockout. The `$.getJSON` call works and brings the JSON string back but for whatever reason the UI doesn't get updated. Here is my code:

```
    //View
       function companyViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.CompanyName = ko.observable();
    self.TenantID = ko.observable();
    self.Name = ko.observable();
    self.Host = ko.observable();
    self.Status = ko.observable();
    self.Title = ko.observable();
    self.Theme = ko.observable();
    self.Logo = ko.observable();
    self.ProfileID = ko.observable();
    self.AdminEmail = ko.observable();
    self.Address1 = ko.observable();
    self.Address2 = ko.observable();
    self.City = ko.observable();
    self.State = ko.observable();
    self.Zip = ko.observable();
    self.Country = ko.observable();
    self.Phone = ko.observable();
}    

var vm = new companyViewModel();

$.getJSON('http://localhost:8644/api/TenantAPI/5',
            function (tempData)
            {
                alert(JSON.stringify(tempData));
                ko.mapping.fromJSON(tempData, {}, vm);
            })
    .fail(handleModelFailed)
    .error(handleModelFailed);

ko.applyBindings(vm);


function handleModelFailed(jqXHR, txtStatus, error) {
    alert(txtStatus);
}

function populateModel(data) {
    myJSON = data;
    alert(JSON.stringify(myJSON));
}
```

And here is the `JSON` recieved by the browser:

```
{"$id":"1","ChangeSets":[],"Departments":[],"Escalations":[],"SLAs":[],"TenantID":1,"Name":"iGoGreen","Host":"iGoGreen.solver.com","Status":"Active","Title":"iGoGreen","Theme":null,"Logo":null,"ProfileID":null}
```

API Controller:

```
 // GET api/tenant/5
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
    {
        //TODO:Remove hard-coded value
        var tenant = _tenantDataService.GetTenant("iGoGreen.solver.com");
        var response = Request.CreateResponse<Tenant>(HttpStatusCode.OK, tenant);
        response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        return response;
    }
```

Finally the HTML Snippet:

```
    <section id="basicInfoSection" class="container data-group col-md-offset-1 col-md-10" style="border: 1px solid silver;">
    <h3>Company info:</h3><hr />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Company Name:</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Company Name" data-bind="text: CompanyName" class="form-control textbox-with-icon company removeWidthDefault">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <span class="badge" data-placement="right" title="Enter the name of your company">?</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Web address:</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <span class="form-control-static">
                <b class="text-highlighted example-url-lg">
                    http:// <input type="text" data-bind="value: Host" class="inline form-control  " style="width: 150px;">
                    .localhost.net
                </b>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <span class="badge" data-placement="right" title="Enter the URL you want to use to access your company's localhost.net portal">?</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
</section>
```

Also, I have tried several approaches such as using ko.mapping.fromJSON etc to no avail. I am sure it is something basic/small that I am missing ... any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

The UI isn't updating because your view model is never being populated with the fetched JSON. In your `$.getJSON` call to the server, you are passing in the viewmodel (`self`) instead of a function (see [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)) to populate the viewmodel. Try this (using mapping plugin):

```
   function companyViewModel() {
       var self = this;
       self.CompanyName = ko.observable();
       ... the rest of your observables
   }

   var vm = new companyViewModel();
   $.getJSON('http://localhost:8644/api/TenantAPI/5', function (data) {
       ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, vm);
   });

   ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: Unfortunately no ... I have updated the original post and incorporated the changes you suggested. Also, you can tell that KO is trying to apply the bindings because when you comment out a few properties you start seeing errors such as "[PropertyName] is undefined" ... not sure why the UI is not getting updated. I have verified and the HTML data-bind matches the Property Name exactly.

Comment: Correction, error '[PropertyName] is undefined' is probably because of data-bind="PropertyName" not being able to map to a ViewModel.Property.

Comment: @Robert could you post the code from your Web API controller method and a snippet of your html where you are data binding?

Comment: @Robert I just noticed in your updated code, that your mapping is omitting the second parameter which is the mapping options. If you look at the code I posted, my mapping is taking in three parameters - the JSON data, the mapping options ( which are empty in this case, or `{}`), and then the viewmodel. So change your code from `ko.mapping.fromJSON(tempData, vm);` to `ko.mapping.fromJSON(tempData, {}, vm);`

Comment: I originally had it but then I removed it to see if that would have any affect. I just added the mapping options {} back and tried but it still doesn't work. Will update the post to reflect that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46970/discussion-between-rwisch45-and-robert)